# android how to keep large List<String[]> while application runs

Tags: android, out-of-memory

What is the best way to keep a `List<String[]>` while my application runs? I am having problems with my approach. It most of the time gives me an OutOfMemory Error since the list is too big.

The `List<String[]>` is the result of parsing a csv file that I have downloaded online. What I do is parse the csv in an activity then save its result in a static class member like:

```
String url = "http://xxx/pdf/pms/pms_test.csv";
try {
    InputStream input = new URL(url).openStream();
    CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
    SchedController.sched = reader.readAll();
    input.close();
}
```

...then access `ClassName.sched` on different activities.

I am doing this so that the parsed data will be available in every activity... And I don't have to parse again. What can I do to improve it?

Comment: Should apply Paging Mechanism with "Loading More..." functionality. It will help you to achieve smoothness and speed also.

Comment: Would holding it in a service and passing the data between services and activity help?

Comment: Are you storing the parsed values in a `Collection` like a `HashTable` or `ArrayList`?

Comment: I generally parse and store in a `HashTable` in name value pairs and make that as static so that it is available throughout the app.Didn't cause any issues till date.

Comment: @PareshMayani how is that? sorry, this is the first time i have heard of Paging mechanism...tried searching it but can't seem to find a detailed explanation other than from Wiki.. Thanks

Comment: @Abhilasha hmm.. no. I am using `List<String[]>`... What's the difference on using a `List<E>` and a `HashTable`? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can have 2 approaches.

1. You save the **file** and parse it in a lazy loading way
2. You create a **database** and save your data.

I suggest you to create a database, this is not difficult and let you to manage well your data. You can do easily lazyLoading with cursor, or use a ORM ([ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) / [Greendao](http://greendao-orm.com/))... I think this is the best way and the fastest to load your data.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: From what I understand, lazy loading works well when you don't have to get and display everything at once... but in my case, going through the whole csv file is crucial because the results I need is based on a schedule's presence in the file.. However, I'll try to read about creating a database for it. Wish it wasn't hard. I thought of it the first time I saw the csv file but used the approach I said above instead...

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to Paresh's comment.
I can suggest something similar I used in my app.

For example I need to display list of Items in a store. (Each item will have ID, name and cost).

To achieve this I first make a request to server to get number of items, say *itemCount*.
Now I set a limit to number of items displayed in a page say 100. 
If the *itemCount* is greater than 100, I display an alert saying only 100 items will be displayed and a next `button` can be added to download next set of items.
Or if it is a search you can ask user to go back and refine the search.
If *itemCount* is  less than 100 then you will not have any issues

This way *Paging* can be implemented to avoid `OutOfMemory` issues

Comment: Ah... I think I can't do that (not really sure..) You see, my app returns schedule details that are formatted in the csv file. Everytime I am searching for a schedule, I have to go through the whole csv to return the right results. Also, the client requires the app to be usable even if its offline...

Comment: Then I guess donwload everything once, parse and saving in Database is better than keeping every thing in runtime memory(which is causing OutOfMemory).And accessing it when needed to display. May be while designing the database you can categorize data in multiple tables such that you don't spend too much time filtering it.This way app can work even if it is _offline_

Comment: guess so too... Thanks for your time! :)